# Is it possible to express the derivative of the Bessel function of the Second Kind, using elementary functions, if $n$ is an integer, or half integer?

Tags: derivatives, bessel-functions, elementary-functions

I was looking at the Bessel Function of the Second Kind, $Y_n(x)$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bessel+function+of+the+second+kind

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat415/lecture16.pdf

and found that it's derivative is $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(Y_n\left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(Y_{n-1}\left(x\right)-Y_{n+1}\left(x\right)\right)$$ I'm still not sure if the Derivative of the Bessel Function of the Second Kind can be expressed in terms of $x$, using elementary functions, when $n$ is either an integer or half integer.

Is it possible to express the Derivative of the Bessel of the Second Kind in terms of $x$ using elementary functions when n is an integer or half integer?  If so what is the method to figure out the elementary functions that the Derivative of Bessel Function of the Second kind is expressed in for any integer or half integer value of $n$?

Comment: For Bessel functions $Y_{k+1/2}(x)$ with integer $k$, that's [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn).

Comment: @ProfessorVector is there a formula for finding out what those elementary functions are for any integer value of $k$?

Comment: The formula $$y_n(x)=-(-x)^n\left(\frac1x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{\cos x}x$$ in my link is explicit enough, and $y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3$ are still more so, I'd say.